# Cursor causes error in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-7.2

When I was programming in Java with NetBeans, I found a strange error.  When I ran the application with my cursor on certain lines, it would give me an error code without reason and display random junk in the applet.  If I click to a different line in the editor, however, it runs perfectly without a hitch.  It seems to be that when my cursor is on specific lines involving a particle array, although I've checked twice and there are no obvious errors in the array scripts.
Is there any reason for the glitches?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes Netbeans goes crazy sometimes, especially when debugging if I never shut off my laptop for a while. Starts jumping into function I never hit, etc.... Not sure why.